# Calculating completion potential using in-cell formula in Excel

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

I am trying to define an in-cell formula to calculate a potential transaction completion rate in Excel. I'm having difficulty finding a solution and I'm hoping someone can provide some direction if not a solution.

**Inputs:** There will be two variables in adjacent columns:

- x is the number of seconds needed to complete a single transaction
- y is the number of seconds between transaction start times

**Objective:** Find the total transaction completion rate possible in 60 seconds comprised of the number of transactions that can be fully completed in 60 seconds plus the sum percentage of partially complete transactions. Results will always be positive but will approach zero as `x` and `y` increase.

Added challenges:

- If `y` is greater than or equal to 60 seconds, only one transaction can start
- If `x` is greater than 60 seconds, then each transaction is a partial-complete

The easiest way to explain what I am trying to do is through examples.

If the solution were drawn on a timeline, the timeline would look like this:

```
Example 1
let x = 30 seconds
let y = 10 seconds
let ti = a transaction where i is the transaction number

t1 starts @ 0 seconds, ends @ 30 seconds == first complete transaction
t2 starts @ 10 seconds, ends @ 40 seconds == second complete transaction
t3 starts @ 20 seconds, ends @ 50 seconds == third complete transaction
t4 starts @ 30 seconds, ends @ 60 seconds == fourth complete transaction
t5 starts @ 40 seconds, time expires @ 60 seconds == (60-40)/30 = 2/3 of a complete transaction
t6 starts @ 50 seconds, time expires @ 60 seconds == (60-50)/30 = 1/3 of a complete transaction

The total transaction completion rate is 1+1+1+1+2/3+1/3 = 5
```

[image]

Here are few other examples with various inputs.

```
Example 2
let x = 40 seconds
let y = 10 seconds
let ti = a transaction where i is the transaction number

t1 starts @ 0 seconds, ends @ 40 seconds == first complete transaction
t2 starts @ 10 seconds, ends @ 50 seconds == second complete transaction
t3 starts @ 20 seconds, ends @ 60 seconds == third complete transaction
t4 starts @ 30 seconds, time expires @ 60 seconds == (60-30)/40 = 3/4 of a complete transaction
t5 starts @ 40 seconds, time expires @ 60 seconds == (60-40)/40 = 1/2 of a complete transaction
t6 starts @ 50 seconds, time expires @ 60 seconds == (60-50)/40 = 1/4 of a complete transaction

The total transaction completion rate is 1+1+1+3/4+1/2+1/4 = 4.5

Example 3
let x = 70 seconds
let y = 60 seconds
let ti = a transaction where i is the transaction number

t1 starts @ 0 seconds, time expires @ 60 seconds == (60-0)/70 = 6/7 of a complete
no further transaction starts because y >= 60

Result: 6/7 = ~0.857 

Example 4
let x = 70 seconds
let y = 30 seconds
let ti = a transaction where i is the transaction number

t1 starts @ 0 seconds, time expires @ 60 seconds == (60-0)/70 = 6/7 of a complete
t2 starts @ 30 seconds, time expires @ 60 seconds == (60-30)/70 = 3/7 of a complete
no further transaction starts because y >= 60

Result: 9/7 = ~1.286


Example 4
let x = 10 seconds
let y = 60 seconds
let ti = a transaction where i is the transaction number

t1 starts @ 0 seconds, ends @ 10 seconds == first complete transaction
no further transaction starts because y >= 60

Result: 1
```

I feel there should be an elegant solution to this, but I haven't been able to find it.

I can calculate the total completed when `x` and `y` are less than 60...

```
complete = (60 - x)/y + 1
```

...but this excludes the partial-completes, and it doesn't work when y >= 60.

I prefer not to use VBA, but helper columns are acceptable if necessary.

All thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no version constraints, as indicated by your tags, you can try:

- Enter in some cell and the results will spill down

***Edited to correct for case where `y` not a perfect divisor of `60`***

```
=BYROW(
    $A$2:$B$7,
    LAMBDA(arr,
        LET(
            start, SEQUENCE(
                ,
                CEILING(60 / INDEX(arr, 2), 1),
                0,
                INDEX(arr, 2)
            ),
            end, BYCOL(
                start + INDEX(arr, 1),
                LAMBDA(arr, MIN(arr, 60))
            ),
            SUM(end - start) / INDEX(arr, 1)
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ron Rosefeld -- This is very close. It works for the example numbers, but in practice, it didn't capture the last possible transaction start in several cases.   Adding 1 to the start sequence seems to fix the issue `...start, SEQUENCE(, 60 / INDEX(arr, 2) +1,...`

For example: x = 112 and y = 28; formula result = 0.821429

Manual:
Start @ 0 -- 60/112 = 0.535714
Start @ 28 -- (60-28)/112 = 0.285714
Start @ 56 -- (60-58)/112 = 0.035714
manual result = 0.85714...  (0.035714 greater than the formula)

If you agree and revise your code I will accept this answer.

Comment: @AWaddington I'm not at my computer just now but I will review it later today. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @AWaddington. The problem only shows when y is not a perfect divisor of 60.  OP's Example 1 suggests 6 starts when, in fact, there are 7. Last one starts at time 60. However, since cut-off is also 60, contribution to result is zero. In fact all OP  examples have an uncounted but zero contributing last start so in these examples the undercount doesn't matter because it does not affect results. However, when y is not a perfect divisor of 60, the undercount erroneously reduces results by the contribution from the final start (as the counterexample in AW's comment shows).

Comment: @AWaddington Please see my edit. I agree with @DMM that there is an error when `y` is not a perfect divisor of 60. I would handle this by replacing the `columns` argument in that function with `CEILING(60/INDEX(arr,2),1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in a `Module`

```
Function EXPTEST(add1 As Range, add2 As Range) As Double
For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((60 / add2), 0)
    If (60 - (i - 1) * add2) / add1 >= 1 Then
        EXPTEST = EXPTEST + 1
    Else
        EXPTEST = EXPTEST + (60 - (i - 1) * add2) / add1
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

This is the test result:

[image]

Comment: and for the benefit of others, this works well and is simple to understand for users.  I needed an in-cell formula (non-VBA) for this particular instance, but otherwise, this is a great option.

Answer (score 0):

The number possible of transaction starting at or before time 60 is
*s* = 1+INT(60/*y*)

These transactions start at times 0, *y*, 2×*y*, ... , (*s*-1)×*y* and
finish at times *x*, *x* + *y*, *x* + 2×*y*, ... , *x* + (*s*-1)×*y*

The number of transactions that are complete by time 60 is
*c* = MAX(1+INT((60-*x*)/*y*),0)

The number of transactions that are started but not completed by time 60 is
*i* = *s* - *c*

and these incomplete transactions started at times
*c*×*y*, (*c*+1)×*y*, ... (*c*+*i*-1)×*y*

These incomplete transactions, respectively, have the following proportions of the transaction undertaken by time 60:
(60-*c*×*y*)/*x*, (60-(*c*+1)×*y*)/*x*, ... , (60-(*c*+*i*-1)×*y*))/*x*

The total "amount" of transaction undertaken by time 60 is the sum of the complete transactions (*c*, above) plus the sum of the proportions undertaken for the incomplete transactions.

The latter is:
(60-*c*×*y*)/*x* + (60-(*c*+1)×*y*)/*x* + ... + (60-(*c*+*i*-1)×*y*)/*x*.

The *k*'th term (*k*=1,...,*i*) of this sum can be written as

(60 - (*c*+*k*-1)×*y*)/*x* =
(60 - (*c*-1)×*y* - *k*×*y*)/*x* =
(60 - (*c*-1)×*y*)/*x* - *k*×*y*/*x*

The first part of the term is
(60 - (*c*-1)×*y*)/*x*

and is the same for all *i* terms  of the sum. Consequently, the sum of the proportions can be re-written as:

*i*×(60 - (*c*-1)×*y*)/*x* - (*y*/*x*)×(1+2+...+*i*)

The very final term  of 1+2+...+*i* is, as every schoolboy/girl should know, an arithmetic progression, and can be simplified to
*i*×(*i*+1)/2,

leaving the sum of proportions from the incomplete transactions as
*i*×(60-(*c*-1)×*y*)/*x* - (*y*/*x*)×*i*×(*i*+1)/2

So, the "amount" of transaction completed by time 60 for a sequence of transactions starting at time 0 which each have a duration of *x* and inter-start time of *y* is:

*c* + *i*×(60-(*c*-1)×*y*)/*x* + (*y*/*x*)×*i*×(*i*+1)/2

where:

*c* = MAX(1+INT((60-*x*)/*y*),0)

*i* = *s* - *c*, and

*s* = 1+INT(60/*y*)

This can be compressed into a single formula in Excel (but I wouldn't recommend it) as:

`=MAX(1+INT((60-A2)/B2),0) + (1+INT(60/B2)-MAX(1+INT((60-A2)/B2),0))*(60-(MAX(1+INT((60-A2)/B2),0)-1)*B2)/A2 - (B2/A2)*(1+INT(60/B2)-MAX(1+INT((60-A2)/B2),0))*(2+INT(60/B2)-MAX(1+INT((60-A2)/B2),0))/2`

where *x* and *y*, respectively, are in cells `A2` and `B2`.

Assigning *s*, *c* and *i* to helper cells `C2`, `D2` and `E2` allows for the more readable formula of:

`=D2 + E2*(60-(D2-1)*B2)/A2 - (B2/A2)*E2*(E2+1)/2`

[image: Screenshot illustrating implementation]

Comment: I presume the mark down was by amathematical illiterate.

Comment: I had wondered about triangular numbers and arithmetic progression but never found the application. I look forward to reviewing your response in more detail. It works. The results match those of the other solutions and the manual calculations.

Comment: @AWddington, if you have a version that supports the `LET()` function then obviously that can be used as an alternative to the helpers for _s_, _c_ and _i_.  columns. The difficulty noted in your OP for calculating the number of completed transactions is overcome by wrapping the calculation within  `MAX( ... ,0)`. This avoids calculating negative values.